# Is there a way to change the css property of 'this' in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6

I am wondering if there is a way to change the styling of an element when using 'this' in js es6. I have the following code below:

```js
const mobileSubItems = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-menu-overlay__item");
openSubMenu = (e) => {
  console.log(this);
}

for (var i = 0; i < mobileSubItems.length; i++) {
  mobileSubItems[i].addEventListener('click', openSubMenu);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu-overlay__item-content" style="maxHeight:0;">Test 1</div>
<div class="mobile-menu-overlay__item-content" style="maxHeight:0;">Test 2</div>
<div class="mobile-menu-overlay__item-content" style="maxHeight:0;">Test 3</div>
```

I'd like the openSubmenu code to, instead, be something like the below:

```
openSubMenu = (e) => {
  this.style.maxHeight = "none";
}
```

Comment: Don't use arrow functions when you mean regular functions. `openSubMenu = function(e) { this.style.maxHeight = "none"; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the provided logic. But because of the arrow functions, you are losing the this context. Instead, use the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property.

```
var openSubMenu = (e)=> {
  e.target.style.maxHeight = '240px';
}
```

or

If you want this to point to the clicked element, define the openSubMenu function with the function keyword.

```
var openSubMenu = function(e) {
  this.style.maxHeight = '240px';
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL4qt4jt/1/)

Comment: This is a different way of solving the problem, but does not actually answer the question of how to use `this` to reference the DOM element that triggered the event.

Comment: and if there are divs next to each one of those with the classname "test" I would say:  e.target.closest(".test").style.maxHeight = '240px';
?

Comment: closest is a jQuery function, so you could use it like $(e.target).closest(...).css()

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the css property of 'this' in javascript es6?

Yes, use a normal function definition for your callback instead of a fat arrow definition so the value of `this` that the triggered event sets will be there for you.

Because you're using a fat arrow function, the value of `this` in your `openSubMenu()` function is not taken from the caller, but is taken from the function declaration context (the "lexical" value of `this`).  If you instead declare `openSubMenu()` as a normal function, then the click event will set `this` to be the DOM element that caused the event and you can then use `this` to set the style on it.

So, change to this:

```
function openSubMenu(e) {
    console.log(this);
}
```

People need to remember that fat arrow functions are not ONLY a function declaration shortcut.  They also affect the value of `this`.  **So, if you want the value of `this` that the caller of your function sets, then don't use a fat arrow function because the fat arrow declaration causes a different value of `this` to be used.**

---

As I presume you already know, you could have also referenced the DOM element that triggered the event using `e.target`, but since you explicitly asked about how to make `this` work, that's what I've shown you above.